# Is the goddess Bhumi the Maya of Atman

Tags: atma, maya, earth

Bhumi is the coat the dress of Atman so if all  sentient beings are born.
 How did  Atman become a jiva Atman ?

Comment: What does your question even mean?

Comment: Maya = illusory power of Brahman..... Bhumi = the earth/ earth element/ ground.......where did you find the connection with Atman? What is your offline source of information?

Comment: @Arkaprabha Majumdar In Hinduism Bhumi is the Goddess of the earth, the mother the soil the body for all sentient beings on earth.

Comment: @FrankHestermann .. yeah I know who Bhumi us. The question is, how are you linking Bhumi to Atman. Apparently she has no link to Maya or Atman.

Comment: @Arkaprabha Majumdar, its about joining the dots. "GOD" Wears many clouds and on our so called decent we arrive at Kali as Maha Maya and with her 8 elements and the god of time the phenomial world is born. Bhumi is part of that phenomenal world. She is temporal and Atman is eternal and so I asked is she the Maya of Atman.

Comment: @FrankHestermann ... Bhumi has no connection to Atman from the basis of what you're asking. Bhumi is not temporal, Bhumi just represents the Earth. Earth in the physical realm is temporal. Maya of Atman, what do you mean by Maya of Atman?

Answer (score 5):

What you have written in the body of the question isn't making much sense to me :). Probably you may want to add some more stuffs to the body so as to make it more clear.

For the question in the title though the following is an answer:

From Maya everything is created. Even Bhumi or Earth is the product of Maya. So, Bhumi being a product of Maya can not be Maya itself/herself.

From Maya actually the three Gunas (Sattva, Rajas and Tamas) are born. So, in that way Maya becomes the creator of everything because everything is formed of the three Gunas.

See the following passage:

> 21-23. O Dvaipâyana! Thus saying, Visnu stopped. I was greatly
>   astonished and asked that Eternal Vâsudeva, the Deva of the Devas, the
>   Lord of the World, “O Lord of Ramâ! What is the form of Mâyâ? How is
>   She? What is the measure of Her strength? Where She resides? Whose
>   substratum is She? Kindly tell these to me. O Preserver of the
>   Universe! I am greatly desirous to see Mâyâ; Shew Her to me quickly. O
>   Lord of Ramâ! I am very eager to know Mâyâ. Be graciously pleased to
>   describe tome the glory of Mâyâ.” 24-36. **Visnu said :-- Mâyâ resides
>   everywhere throughout this whole Universe; Her nature consists of the
>   three Gunas; She is the substratum of all; She is omniscient, and
>   acknowledged by all; invisible, and of diverse forms.**
>
> . Nârada said :-- O Thou whose only wealth consists in asceticism! I
>   am now describing to you all those good stories; hear attentively. O
>   Muni! This Mâyâ and Her Power are incomprehensible even by those who
>   are the foremost amongst the Yogins. **This whole Universe, moving and
>   non-moving, from Brahmâ to the blade of grass, is enchanted by that
>   Unborn and Incomprehensible Mâyâ; therefore no one can escape from the
>   hands of that Mâyâ.**
>
> **Devi Bhagavatam Book 6, Chapter 28.**

Note that here Maya is stated to be unborn but the same can not be said of Bhumi or Earth. Because Earth came into existence at some point in time. It was of course not existing eternally.

**So, Maya and Bhumi are not the same.**  Although to say that Bhumi or Earth is an aspect of Maya is alright. Furthermore, that Earth is a highly praised Vedic deity is also true.

If you need more references then please ask I'll try to provide.